# SQL Replication - Need to replicate only data on exiting tables of the subscription database

Tags: sql-server, replication, database-replication, transactional-replication

I have a specific requirement in `Transactional Replication`, but I am not sure whether it is achievable or not. Could you please help me out if there is any possible way to achieve the same.

**Requirement:**

As per the requirement, there will be two databases. One is the `publication database` and another is `subscription database`.

I want to replicate some of the `tables (articles)` of the `publication database` to the `subscription database`. But what I want is to replicate data only. Because I want to keep those `tables (replicating tables)` to always present in the `subscription database`, they may be the empty table initially and when replication starts, these tables may get their data from `publication database`.

But I don't want the `replication` to create these tables for me in `subscription database`. I want to use already created tables. They will have the same schema as `publication database` tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you configure a publication, you can set the properties for articles. One of the article properties is called **Action if name in use**. You can set that to the option **Keep existing object unchanged**.